# How to restrict webview content to zoomout below 100%

Tags: android, css, webview, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

Hello Developers,

I am working on a project where I am using webview so here I am using the default property of webview to zoom in and zoom out on pinch zoom after enabling the properties-

```
 w.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
 w.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

After enabling it zoom in and zoom out is working perfectly in Android versions below Kitkat, but what my problem is, in Kitkat the webview contents are zooming out too small. I'd like to prevent from things from zooming out - content should always fit the screen.

I have tried the meta tag properties like this, but with Kitkat it's not working properly ie-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height ,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />";
```

Please suggest me how I can handle this in Android Kitkat with Chromimum webkit.

Thanks to all in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `setUseWideViewPort` WebSettings API might be making the viewport wider than it needs to be, but that would only be the case if you *don't* have a viewport meta tag.

From what you've posted it looks like:

- the viewport meta tag is doing what it's supposed to do: `width=device-width` may be more pixels than your contents size. Try setting it to the width of your content.
- the tag may not be parsing correctly (try connecting DevTools and see if there are any error messages on the console),
- you're hitting some bug, see if setting `targetSdkVersion` to 19 or disabling `setUseWideViewPort` helps.